# Let $x\geq 29, x \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the product of all primes that are less or equal to $x$ is greater than $2^x$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am interested in ways to prove that claim, I came across it when reading about the analysis of the average case complexity of Rabin-Karp's algorithm for string matching.

Comment: [This post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44207/asymptotics-of-product-of-consecutive-primes) discuses asymptotics of it.

Comment: [This blog post](http://godplaysdice.blogspot.com/2007/09/hand-waving-asymptotics-of-primorial.html) does some computation of bounds for it, it might have useful techniques for you.